# PHP getting special characters from database

Tags: php, special-characters

I have an issue with the special characters. For ex. In the database is written "A & A" (database is set on utf8-unicode-ci). 
I am retrieving in autosugest list the values correctly with:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $keywords = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
 echo "<keywords>". $keywords ."</keywords>";       
}
```

When I click to select the "A & A" in the input field is filled as  A & amp; A

the header is set on :`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Can you please let me know how to display the special character?

Comment: That's the work of htmlspecialchars I presume ?

Comment: You are HTML escaping one time too many somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert from `A &amp; A` to `A&A`, use [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode) on the text.
If you want to convert from `A&A` to `A &amp; A` use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

In your case removing `htmlspecialchars` operation on the text pulled from your database will do.
Since your issue appears to be with the `&` character being replaced with `&amp;`, maybe running something like `$text = str_replace("&amp;", "&", htmlspecialchars($text));` will work better for you, and prevents XSS.

Comment: He doesn't want to convert anything, but he still does which is why he's seeing the &amp;.

Comment: You want to promote XSS ?

Comment: @HamZa At least be constructive. Saying "Do you want it to break" doesn't tell us anything aside from the fact that it might not work.

Comment: @Parrotmaster My bad though, I shouldn't have skimped on the obvious XSS scenario. :p

Comment: @Parrotmaster I'm being constructive, have you ever heard of XSS and how to block it ?

Comment: @HamZa Asking "You want to promote XSS" is in no way constructive. You didn't give me any information or pointers, and your statement isn't even a clear question. You could have said something like "Your code will cause a security issue and you should do [code] instead". Yet you chose to be as vague as you possibly could. Next time be more clear. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php

Comment: @Parrotmaster Sorry to be vague, wasn't my intention :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have "A & A" in the database, htmlspecialchars will do that.

Remove htmlspecialchars.

Comment: You want to promote XSS ?

Comment: @HamZa What? Stay on topic please.

Comment: I'm on topic, why do you think one is using `htmlspecialchars` ?

Comment: thanks for all your inputs. If I remove `htmlspecialchars` then in the autosuggest list doesn't appear any name with special chars. also when I add `htmlspecialchars_decode`

Comment: @Lilou I'd recommend using htmlspecialchars to turn your "A & A" into "A &amp; A" before you upload it into the database (or put "A &amp; A" in the database). If you use htmlspecialchars_decode after it will be more secure. See Jimmie Lin's answer.

Comment: Let's take an example of a commenting system. A wild user tries to inject code in a comment like this: `<script>alert('hello');</script>`, when another user opens that section, the database will fetch that comment and display it. Now the other user wil get an alert. This is a really simple case, but hackers could load an iframe or custom exploit. To prevent that, you could use `htmlspecialchars`, it will convert `<>` to `&lt;&gt;` and thus making the script tag not work. Ofcourse, you may argue that one should filter tags from the beginning with [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Comment: @HamZa You should put this in an answer (or update Jimmie Lin's answer with this) since it's pretty important information.

Comment: @Parrotmaster Yes I agree with you, I can do that for the future inserts, but at the moment in the database there are over 2000 names that most of them have some special characters.

Comment: @Parrotmaster I can't since it doesn't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @HamZa But it is important information that is related to the solution, and therefore should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Its better use `rawurlencode` before you inserting the value to database. Then whenever you fetching the value, use `rawurldecode`. I think it may solve your problem.

```
   rawurldecode($row['name']);
```

Check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php

Comment: Please read the link you have provided. It says `The URL to be encoded.`, so this is by no mean to be used on random data.

Comment: Please provide a compelling reason to use either HTML or URL encoding for data in the database, and specifically why URL encoding beats HTML encoding.

Comment: This is correct answer, please try to read the documentation.